# Shared folder doesn't send email invitation

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, shared-directory

My code to share a sharepoint folder is OK but it doesnt send email invitation to the external user. How can I add this in my code?

By "send email invitation", I mean the same feature that we can find in SharePoint:

[image]

Code:

```
Folder folderToShare = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(urlDestination);

var role = clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Editor);
var roleBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext) { role };
folderToShare.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);

User user = web.EnsureUser("my email adress here");
folderToShare.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleBinding);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: The [`Web.EnsureUser` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.ensureuser.aspx) takes the login name as a parameter, not email address - "The logon name (Domain\User_Alias) of the user."

Comment: This code works fine with the email adress. I have to use an email adress because it's an external client and i have to invite him by mail. After this code, The client have access to shared folder but he doesnt receive an invitation in a email. I want to know if it's possible to send invitation by code like we can do by sharepoint application (see the image). Thank you for your reply

Comment: The docs say the EnsureUser method "Checks whether the specified logon name belongs to a valid user of the website, and if the logon name does not already exist, adds it to the website". Nothing about sending email.

Comment: Yes i know but it's ok with the email. I just need the email invitation to complete my code but i think logon or email is the same because it's functionnal.